# "did we do" why Do?

Tags: past-tense

Yesterday I stumbled upon this sentence in a TV show "did we do what we did". I feel I don't really grasp why we use "do" if we are talking about the past (asking about the thing we just did).

Comment: _Did_ takes the infinitive form of the verb. "I went to church this morning." "Did you go last Sunday too?"

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Maciej.  Are you able to remember more in the way of the context in which this was said.  Probably not, but it would help if you  could say what was being talked about.  There are various ways in these words might be uttered.  An any of them, it is a special way of speaking for emphasis.  For example:  1)  Only because the landlord told us to did we do what we did;  or 2) Once we got there, boy, did we do what we did!  Can you give any more detail to help?

Comment: Hi Tuffy. Yes. I watched Space Force 9 episode I believe. They basically landed on the moon on China territory without permission and one scientist asks this question.

Comment: Most likely it's a version of something like *Wow! Did we **really** do that?,* where "that" = *whatever we just did*. Speaker is using a rhetorical question to express surprise - expected answer being ***Yes**! Obviously we just did it!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "did we do what we did". I feel I don't really grasp why we use "do"
> if we are talking about the past

Compare with the following:

Did you **like** that?

Did she **eat** that?

Did John **go** there?

Did Mary **do** that?

In every case, "did" is the past tense of the auxiliary verb "do".  An auxiliary verb is used in conjunction with the **bare infinitive** of the main verb.

---

Comment: Thank you Chasly!